# Changing the color of the selected value in an uneditable jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How can I change the color of the selected value in an uneditable jcombobox?

I know I have to use a custom renderer to change the color of the items appearing in the dropdown list of a combobox. I'm also aware of the setForeground() method that can be used with the editor component of the combobox, but that only works for editable comboboxes. I also know that I can play around with the UIManager class, but that affects these properties globally.

However, these are not what I need. This image

[image]

shows the part I'd like to affect.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change the color of the selected value in an uneditable
>   jcombobox?

- change value for `UIManager`

> here is basic workaround for editable (with removing Background to
>   current background, notice there is shortcut in MetalComboBoxButton,
>   then is Look and Feel sensitive, works correctly for Metal and
>   substance L&f only)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton;

public class MyComboBox {

    private Vector<String> listSomeString = new Vector<String>();
    private JComboBox someComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JComboBox editableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JComboBox non_EditableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JFrame frame;

    public MyComboBox() {
        //for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            listSomeString.add("-");
            listSomeString.add("Snowboarding");
            listSomeString.add("Rowing");
            listSomeString.add("Knitting");
            listSomeString.add("Speed reading");
        //}
//
        someComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        someComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        someComboBox.setEditable(true);
        someComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        ((JTextField) someComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
//
        editableComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        editableComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        editableComboBox.setEditable(true);
        JTextField text = ((JTextField) editableComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent());
        text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        JComboBox coloredArrowsCombo = editableComboBox;
        Component[] comp = coloredArrowsCombo.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {// hack valid only for Metal L&F
            if (comp[i] instanceof MetalComboBoxButton) {
                MetalComboBoxButton coloredArrowsButton = (MetalComboBoxButton) comp[i];
                coloredArrowsButton.setBackground(null);
                break;
            }
        }
//
        non_EditableComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        non_EditableComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
//
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        frame.add(someComboBox);
        frame.add(editableComboBox);
        frame.add(non_EditableComboBox);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //System.out.println(listSomeString.size());
        //System.out.println(someComboBox.getItemCount());
        //System.out.println(editableComboBox.getItemCount());
        //System.out.println(non_EditableComboBox.getItemCount());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
        UIManager.put("JTextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.magenta));
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.blue));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyComboBox aCTF = new MyComboBox();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that this solution only changes the color of the selected value of the uneditable combobox if it's literally selected (after selecting a value) and if it loses focus, its color changes back. Also, this affects all comboboxes, I only want to change the color of specific ones.

Comment: @József Legoza not clear your comment, have to elaborating little bit more, is required to see on screen, which Item is selected, don't to confuse user ....

Comment: I'd like to set the text color of the selected value (by selected I mean the part to the left of the dropdown arrow) to anything other than black. If I user UIManger, all comboboxes will have the same properties, but I only want to change the color of a specific combobox. Try the following in your example: select a value in the 3rd combobox and then click on one of the other comboboxes. The text color of the 3rd combobox switches back from blue to black. I want the text color to remain blue in this case too.

Comment: What renderer should I use? I tried using a custom ListCellRenderer, but that only works for the dropdown list, it doesn't affect the color of the selected value (the one next to the arrow).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Where/how should I override them? I tried using 'isSelected' and 'hasFocus' in 'getListCellRendererComponent', but these are parameters, I cannot override them, so that's probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: then another hint, easiest of ways, extract JList from JComboBox, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412981/714968) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9323074/714968),

Answer (score 0):

make the comboBox editable

get the comboBox's editor component

set the editorComponent to focusable(false)

not sure this is what you're after, as you'll still be able to change the selected item, but not able to focus on the editorComponent to change the item.

Comment: I'd like to change the color without making the combobox editable.

Comment: @Michael Dunn then is changed Buttons background too, for editable JComboBox